# how to open pdf file in chrome or safari without downloading in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, document

how to display pdf file on chrome or safari when user tap on pdfButton. i am new to iOS and document displaying concept. following data i am getting from the server.

```
{
  "status" : 200,
  "body" : "<div>Hi Attachment,<\/div><div><br><\/div><div>Attachment Test<br><\/div>",
  "attachment" : "http:\/\/192.168.1.46:3000\/system\/images\/178\/mca%282016-2019%29transfer_certificates_original.pdf?1528805255",
  "sender" : "Dr.P.Shanthi(employee@inmeghcms.in)",
  "message" : "Details fetched successfully",
  "time" : "12 Jun 2018",
  "profile" : "http:\/\/192.168.1.46:3000\/assets\/female.png",
  "subject" : "TEST"
}
```

Comment: you can use `UIDocumentInteractionController` or `Webkit`

Comment: direct path i can use to display.. @Anbu.karthik

Comment: ya sure , you can use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi try this following code , i am using @ Binesh code and i have updated to swift 4.0.

```
var docController:UIDocumentInteractionController!
    let pdfUrl = NSURL(string: "Use your url")

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        downloadPDfDoc(pdfUrl: pdfUrl!)
    }

    @IBAction func pdfViewAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        docController.presentOptionsMenu(from: self.view.frame, in: self.view, animated: true)
    }


func downloadPDfDoc(pdfUrl : NSURL) {
    let urlTest = self.pdfUrl!.absoluteString
    let pdfUrl = NSURL(string: urlTest!)
    if(pdfUrl != nil){
        let pdfRequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(url: pdfUrl! as URL)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(pdfRequest as URLRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main) {(response, data, error) in
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            if(httpResponse?.statusCode == 200 && error == nil){
                let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask).first! as NSURL

                if let fileName = self.pdfUrl!.lastPathComponent {
                    let destinationUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
                    if let data = data {
                        do {
                            try data.write(to: destinationUrl!, options: .atomic)
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                        self.docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: destinationUrl!)
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
}
```

try this one and let me know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the url of the pdf file you can open it in your default web browser using

```
UIApplication.shared.open(url)
```